# How to lazy load data in a Redux application?

Tags: redux

Let's say I got

```
IClientState: {
   firstName: string,
   lastName: string,
   details: IClientDetailsState
}
```

and let's further assume that retrieving `firstName` and `lastName` from a service is cheap, so an action would load all clients in one fel sweep into a parent state

```
xxxxState: {
   clients: IClientState[],
   ...
}
```

However, retrieving `details` for any one client is quite expensive, and they're not exactly needed for display in a list, for instance.

How do I go about this? I was thinking about adding `loading` and `loaded` properties to `IClientDetailsState` and checking for those in a component that requires this data; that component would then fire the action lo load the details if both properties should yield `false`.

The thing is, this check is rather complex from the component's view and to me that's a warning sign that it isn't supposed to be done this way.

So yeah, how do I handle this the proper way?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the problem is related to redux, instead I think you need to rethink your state shape.

I would solve the problem by introducing some new types, for example:

```
IClientBase: {
   firstName: string,
   lastName: string
}

IClientListItem extends IClientBase: {
   index: integer
}

IClientList{
   items: IClientListItem[]
}

IClient extends IClientBase{
   details: IClientDetails
}
```

Now you can gather a list of cheap `IClientListItem` and when the user selects an item you can convert it to `IClient` and inflate with the appropriate client details.